# Android Real time silence detection

Tags: android, audio, real-time

I am trying to take real time audio input from the user and every 300 milli seconds i am taking the average of the samples. i am using PCM 16 bit samples and 44100 sample rate. 
I am reading the data from the audio recorder into a short array and I am printing the average value of all the samples every 300 milliseconds.
But, the problem is the average value appears to be random and it is showing large values even when there is silence( which should not be). 
I want to know if I am using the short array in a right way.

```
public void startRecording() {
    recorder = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_RECOGNITION, SAMPLE_RATE,
            channels, AUDIO_FORMAT, Buffersize);

    recorder.startRecording();

    isRecording = true;
    NoiseSuppressor.create(recorder.getAudioSessionId());
    AcousticEchoCanceler.create(recorder.getAudioSessionId());
    AutomaticGainControl.create(recorder.getAudioSessionId());

    recordingThread = new Thread(new Runnable()

    {
        public void run() {
            writeAudioData();
        }

    });
    recordingThread.start();

}
private void writeAudioData() {

    short data[] = new short[Buffersize/2];

    while(isRecording) {

        samplesread =0;
        value = 0;
        long ftime = System.currentTimeMillis()+300;
        while (ftime > System.currentTimeMillis()) { // loop for taking average of 300 ms

            if(isRecording){
                samplesread += recorder.read(data, 0, Buffersize/2); // reads the data from the recorder and srores in the short array
                int i=0;
                while(i<Buffersize/2) {

                    //value += (long)(data[i]);
                    value += (long)(data[i] & 0xFFFF); // considering the PCM samples are signed I tried this


                    i++;

                }

            }
        }
        show = value;
        div = samplesread;

        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
                tv.setText(""+(show/(div))+" "+div);
                TextView tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                tv2.setText(show+" "+ System.currentTimeMillis());

            }
        },0);

    }

}
```

Comment: I have edited the question to be more specific about the problem.

Comment: The problem is solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The array values consists of signed numbers , so, it was not showing desired results when average was taken. It works when I took RMS values instead of averaging.